# Lumia 530 - no vibration and sounds except bluetooth

Tags: vibration

Lately on my Lumia 530 there is no vibration including when you press the Windows key and no key press sounds including when typing a message or dialing a number. Also when you lock or unlock the phone using the side button and sliding the screen there are no sounds.
When I access the sound menu by pressing the volume up button it says vibration is on. 
For the "Music" app I can only hear the music if I connect it to the car stereo using bluetooth. I can hear sound in the top speaker during a phone call. If I try and do a call when pressing "speaker" there is silence.
It seems the bottom speaker doesn't work at all. I've tried restarting the phone.

Comment: *Not an answer, just based on deductions:* For the "**no vibration**": Check if your "Windows Phone keys vibrate" is enabled on Touch app in Settings. For the "**no sounds**": In ringtones+sounds, verify if it's enabled for play sounds at key press, locking and unlocking, etc. I have no idea what happened with your music app. Any recent changes?

Comment: Hi I took it back to the shop and got a replacement.